# Tag recommendations: sea-water

Tags: discussion, tags

There is no tag for general sea-water related questions.  The only tags up until now that come remotely close are [sea-level](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-level), and [sea-ice](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sea-ice)

Comment: Any user with reputation > 150 can create tags.  If you want a [tag:sea-water] added to a question that needs it, just comment on it and someone may add it.

Comment: Alternatively, dump a link here :-)

Comment: Yeah, and to add on to what @gerrit said: we don't create tags until there's a need for one. If there's a question that needs a tag, we'll create it, but we physically can't create a tag until there's a question that needs it.